# Trying to have authenticated user land on their profile page first instead of home#index - using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My mind is moving slow...this is a simple problem...I know. Please forgive my noobness here...

I want to direct an authenticated user to that users profile page.

Note: I am using Devise.

Note 2: you can see the entire routes.rb file here....pastie.org/6142383

When I do "rake routes" I get this as the route info....

```
profile GET        /profiles/:id(.:format)                       profiles#show
```

So in my routes.rb file I've tried this...

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'profiles#show'
end
```

But I'm getting an error "app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb line 17" which is this...

```
@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
```

So I need to somehow indicate the params[:id] in my routes.rb but I'm confused as to how...

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => '?'  # how to land user on www.website.com/profile/1
end
```

Thank you for your time...

UPDATE:

I'm using the gem 'better errors' (find out about this gem here) http://selfless-singleton.rickwinfrey.com/2012/12/13/better-errors/ the error reads....

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /
Couldn't find Profile without an ID

ProfileControllers#show
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb, line 17
```

and then shows me the exact line...

```
12   end
13 
14   # GET /profiles/1
15   # GET /profiles/1.json
16   def show
17     @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
18 
19     respond_to do |format|
20       format.html # show.html.erb
21       format.json { render json: @profile }
22     end
```

Comment: Forgive *my* noobness, but is this whole `authenticated :user` thing valid? What authentication system is that? As far as I know, most authentication-based redirects happen via filters (`before_filter`), at least in Devise...

Comment: You should post the entire error you're getting at  `app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb line 17`

Comment: now updated with more error info.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want a [Singular Resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) in addition to your other profiles. The following works in Devise:

```
resources :users

authenticate(:user) do
  get '/profile', to: 'users#show'
end
```

And then in your `users_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  if params[:id]
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  else
    # Show the currently logged in user
    @user = current_user
  end
  ....
end
```

To customize where the user lands after successful sign-in, add/customize this method in your `ApplicationController`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 current_user_path
end
```

Other useful guides: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages

Comment: ah so does the first code snippet go inside the routes.rb file in place of the original code ..(see EDIT above)

Comment: You can have both. the `root to:` redefines what the root url is for authenticated user. `/profile` needs to be defined as well, if you want users to have `www.example.com/profile` load the authenticated users's profile. Assuming you're using Devise.

Comment: Devise...yes. Trying to have it so after a user logs in they land to their profile page first instead of home#index

Comment: I appended my answer to address that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  profile_path(resource.profile)
end
```

Comment: I included this in my answer, I'd appreciate it if you could accept it. I would have included it originally if your question was more clear from the beginning :D

Comment: Your answer is close but not exact. I do however, thank you for your time.

Comment: It wasn't exact because your original question was "how do I redirect authenticated user to specific page". No mention of after "sign in", or Devise. You can't use answers that aren't copy-pastable exactly as is?

Comment: note: "using devise" is in the title and in the updated section of the question - cheers.

Comment: Yes, and as an editor I can see when that was added, which was after my answers. But whatever – glhf